# TypeScript install/version error: The term 'tsc' is not recognized

Tags: typescript, installation, version

Setting up a project on a new computer and having issues with TypeScript versioning. I have tried:

```
npm install -g typescript
npm install typescript
npm install -g typescript@2.1.6
npm install -g typescript@2.0.10
```

But every time I try to check the version using:

```
tsc -v
```

I get the following errors:

```
The term 'tsc' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path wa
s included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:4
+ tsc <<<<  -v
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (tsc:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

For reference, the package.json includes:

```
"scripts": {
    "postinstall": "typings install",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "typings": "typings",
    "gulp": "gulp",
    "build-dev": "gulp",
  },
"devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.0",
    "gulp-inline-ng2-template": "^4.0.0",
    "gulp-typescript": "^3.0.2",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "systemjs-builder": "^0.15.26",
    "typescript": "^2.1.6",
    "typings": "^2.0.0"
  }
```

When I run tsc -v on my machine (which is working) I get

```
Version 2.0.10
```

Stuck on what I need to do to install TypeScript so that the tsc command is recognized?

Answer (score 0):

If this issue comes from your command shell.
First install latest npm version then install the TypeScript again with try.

If you are using VS CODE for your development and issue in the VS code terminal when you run tsc build task: If you installed TypeScript from Visual Studio 2015/2017 and path is in environmental variables then first remove it. And do a restart and try again.

I had the same issue like you having and I solved it through above steps.